# How to determine if a row is striked in Excel sheet using OpenPyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm reading an excel file using openpyxl and I face the following issue:

Some cells appear to be striked in excel and their cell strike property is True, I succeed to deal with them using Openpyxl

But some cells appear to be striked in excel but the format cell strike property is False.
This is because row strike property is set.

My problem is that I don't succeed to have access to strike property of row using OpenPyxl

```
    sheet = book[sheet_name]
    for row in sheet[0:sheet.max_row]:
        if sheet.row_dimensions[row[0].row].font.strike:
            break
```

My code never break although some row are striked

What is strange too is that when I look at row_dimensions of my sheet I don't see an entry per line but only for some lines and I don't have any entry for the lines that are striked.
I don't understand on what criteria some line have a corresponding row_dimensions and some have not

Do you know how to proceed or have an idea about that ?

Comment: `sheet[0:sheet.max_row]` does it really work?

Comment: yes it works well !

Comment: As stated in the documentation `row_dimensions` are not really relevant for styling; you **always** have to go cell by cell.

Comment: @CharlieClark  but as I mentionned when the row property strike is set you don't have the information at cell level even in excel. Rows have their own properties that do not appear at cell level so independantly of Openpyxl your solution to deal cell by cell is not relevant

Comment: The specification is quite clear about row and column formatting and openpyxl preseves it for applications that might want to make use of it.

Comment: @CharlieClark in fact it was not appearing in row properties because it was due to conditionnal formatting. It seems that when conditionnal formatting is applied to cells the modifications do not appear in cell format information in Excel and openpyxl reflect that

Comment: Openpyxl is a file format library and not a replacement for an application like Excel.

Comment: I said that even in Excel cell format information do not reflect effect of conditionnal formatting so for sure I don't expect that from Openpyxl

Answer (score 0):

With this input:

[image]

The code below seems to work:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

book = load_workbook(filename='Book 1.xlsx')
sheet = book['Sheet1']

for row_id, row in sheet.row_dimensions.items():
    if row.font.strike:
        print(f'{row_id}: strike row')

for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        cell_id = f'{cell.column_letter}{cell.row}'
        if cell.font.strike:
            print(f'{cell_id}: strike cell')
```

Output:

```
1: strike row
A1: strike cell
B1: strike cell
C1: strike cell
D1: strike cell
B2: strike cell
D2: strike cell
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your piece of code on my excel file and only strike cells messages are displayed. The strike rows are not detected. Which version of openpyxl do you use ?

Comment: `openpyxl==3.1.2` (last version). With this version, I can't use `sheet[0:sheet.max_row]`

Comment: ok I have version 3.0.10, I will ask to have 3.1.2 version

Comment: in fact it was not appearing in row properties because it was due to conditionnal formatting. It seems that when conditionnal formatting is applied to cells the modifications do not appear in cell format information in Excel and openpyxl reflect that